# Excel, compare values and put yes or no

Tags: excel-formula

In Excel, how do I write an equation which will look for a selected value in column A and then see if it exists in column A on another sheet and if it does put yes and no if it does not exist.

I have all the other values I need just need to know if it exists or not and do not want to take the time to do a find on a few thousand values.

Comment: =VLOOKUP and =MATCH are two formulas that might help, with an IFERROR or an IF(ISERROR(...

Answer (score 0):

Assumptions:

- Sheet1 contains the values that you need to check if they exist
- Sheet2 contains the list of values where you will check if sheet1 values exist
- In both sheets, the list of values are in column A

On Sheet1 cell B1 and copied down:

```
=IF(COUNTIF(Sheet2!A:A,A1)>0,"Yes","No")
```